# Searching for low cost alternative for zirconia ceramic crown

Tags: ceramics

I have seen one company call as you have seen below:

> Call for "Development of Zircon Alternative Formulations in Ceramic Tile Glazing Industry"

So I have searched for finding the low-cost alternative for zirconia crowns by these terms:

- [diy ceramic crown](https://www.google.com/search?q=diy+ceramic+criwn&oq=diy+ceramic+criwn&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i10i160l3.5636j0j7&client=ms-android-om-lge&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#sbfbu=1&pi=diy%20ceramic%20crown)
- [low-cost dental crowns](https://www.google.com/search?q=low-cost+dental+crowns&oq=low-cost+dental+crowns&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0i19i22i30j69i60.533j0j7&client=ms-android-om-lge&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)

So as dental industry is more sophisticated on the ceramic and crown I searched the tooth crown and seen this result :

> All-resin dental crowns are the least expensive compared to the other types of crowns listed. However, they can wear down more quickly and fracture more easily than the crowns made of porcelain and metal. For these reasons, resin crowns are rarely a long-term solution and are usually a temporary stand-in.

And found some alternative like porcelain, so I tried to find out how could create one [resin crown (Do It Yourself)](https://www.google.com/search?q=diy+resin+crown&client=ms-android-om-lge&bih=470&biw=360&hl=fa&tbm=vid&sxsrf=ALeKk00o4S5ZwsZn-TvXSZI7k8zY4oXgTg%3A1621577602642&ei=gk-nYLXRJt6EhbIPm5mOuAg&oq=diy+resin+crown&gs_lcp=ChBtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXZpZGVvEAM6BAgjECdQlNAGWNjWBmDt3AZoAHAAeACAAcAEiAHrE5IBCTItMi40LjAuMZgBAKABAaoBEG1vYmlsZS1nd3MtdmlkZW_AAQE&sclient=mobile-gws-video).

So I want to find out some table or comparison, between the :

- cost
- strength
- lifetime

Of the zirconia, porcelain and resin crown with laboratory instruments or if possible as Do It Yourself (DIY) projects.

Thanks.